# How to locate style element in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Hello I want to locate a style element / style elements with Selenium Python,

```
<div style="flex-direction: column; padding-bottom: 65px; padding-top: 0px;">
```

I tried it in ways like:

```
self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='flex-direction:column;padding-bottom:835px;padding-top:0px;']/div")
```

But it does not work. So how do I locate these elements using Selenium Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provided HTML has no `class` attribute. However in your `xpath` you have provided `class` attribute it should be `style` attribute.

```
//div[@style='flex-direction: column; padding-bottom: 65px; padding-top: 0px;']
```

Ideally your code should be

```
self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@style='flex-direction: column; padding-bottom: 65px; padding-top: 0px;']")
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is of a `<div>` element which predominantly contains the `<style>` attribute for it's descendant(s). It would be highly undesirable to locate element/elements based on only the `<style>` attribute.

---

### Solution

Instead it would be better to move to the descendant and locate the element(s) with respect to their (common) attributes. As an example:

- Using `class_name`:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "class_name")
  ```
- Using `id`:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "id")
  ```
- Using `name`:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.NAME, "name")
  ```
- Using `link_text`:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT, "link_text")
  ```
- Using `partial_link_text`:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "partial_link_text")
  ```
- Using `tag_name`:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tag_name")
  ```
- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css_selector")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "xpath")
  ```